# Why does this ONLY search Google?

Tags: c#, webbrowser-control

It skips the navigating to valid URL and goes straight to a Google search. If I enter "stackoverflow.com" into textbox it will Google search for "stackoverflow.com".

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    webBrowser1.Navigate(textBox1.Text); //navigates to url in textbox

    if (!textBox1.Text.StartsWith("http://"))
    {
        webBrowser1.Navigate("http://www.google.ie/search?q=" + (textBox1.Text));
    }
}
```

Comment: Probably should be and if/else instead of `Navigate` then `Navigate` if...

Comment: Obviously "stackoverflow.com" doesn't start with "http://" so why would you expect it to be any different?

Comment: Possibly because navigating to "stackoverflow.com" (without a protocol prefix) will do a search by default in your browser.

Comment: @BradleyDotNET I'm assuming the OP is expecting the browser to navigate to "http://stackoverflow.com" as if it has been typed into the Location box directly

Comment: so if `stackoverflow.com` doesn't start with `http://`, do a google search.  Seems like it will do a google search.

Comment: @DStanley I can see thats what he is expecting, but I don't know *why* he is expecting that when the code clearly does something else. Perhaps he is just that confused.

Comment: Please remember our [Be Nice](http://stackoverflow.com/help/be-nice) policy and that we are welcoming to new devs. The question title combined with body clearly outlines that OP doesn't understand why the code is doing what it does. It falls within the scope of this site as a valid question as a question with a code snippet that is about an algorithm.

Answer (score 5):

That code, in English, basically says "navigate to whatever was entered into the textbox. Then, **IF** whatever you entered into the textbox does NOT start with 'http://' let's immediately do a Google search for it."

Basically you **are** navigating to stackoverflow.com but you're then **immediately** Google searching for it instead. If you want it to act differently, you need to code it differently.

Here's how I'd rework it:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!textBox1.Text.StartsWith("http://"))
    {
        // didn't start with "http://" so search for it
        webBrowser1.Navigate("http://www.google.ie/search?q=" + (textBox1.Text));
    }
    else
    {
        // navigate directly to the URL
        webBrowser1.Navigate(textBox1.Text);
    }
}
```

In an `if-else` statement, only **one** logic path will be chosen based on conditions. It will never be the case that both run.

Answer (score 0):

It searches Google because your logic is saying that 'if the textbox contents doesn't start with `http://` let's do a Google search'. You *are* actually loading `stackoverflow.com`, but you immediately change the page and load Google instead.

You might want the code below with your code modified to 'filter' out and save some memory by not loading `stackoverflow.com` first:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!textBox1.Text.StartsWith("http://") | !textBox1.Text.StartsWith("www") || !textBox1.Text.StartsWith("http://www"))
    {
        webBrowser1.Navigate("http://www.google.ie/search?q=" + (textBox1.Text));
    }
    else
    {
        webBrowser1.Navigate(textBox1.Text); //navigates to url in textbox
    } 
}
```